# How do I get an existing AVPlayerItem from an AVAsset?

Tags: objective-c, avaudioplayer

I'm removing items from my playlist and need to remove their observers.

I found this

`+ playerItemWithAsset:`

but that returns a NEW player item. How do I access the old one if I just have an AVAsset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just have an AVAsset, you have *no* AVPlayerItem. On the contrary:

- A player item belongs to a *player*, not to an *asset*.
- If you've created a player item from an asset, the *asset* belongs to the *player item* (as its `asset` property), not the other way round.

If you have player items already, you need to look through them until you find the one you want - though if you're doing this right, you would already know which one it is, so then you would be able to access its `asset` directly. You don't show any code or explain what you're doing, but if you're finding this difficult, it sounds like you may have designed things upside-down somehow.